# Polynomials invariant under the action of SO(3)

Tags: polynomials, representation-theory, invariant-theory, unitary-matrices

Let $SU(2)$ act on $V_2=\{ax^2+bxy+cy^2:a,b,c\in\mathbb C\}$ by $$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}f(x,y)=f(ax+cy,bx+dy).$$ Then $SU(2)$ also acts on the $n$-th symmetric power $S^n V_2$. Show that $(S^n V_2)^{SU(2)}$ and $k_n[X,Y,Z]^{SO(3)}$ have the same dimension, where $k_n[X,Y,Z]$ is the space of degree n homogeneous polynomials.

Notations: $(S^n V_2)^{SU(2)}$ is the space of elements of $S^n V_2$ invariant under the action of $SU(2)$,
$k_n[X,Y,Z]^{SO(3)}$ is the space of elements in $k_n[X,Y,Z]$ invariant under the action of $SO(3)$, which is given by $\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}f(X,Y,Z)=f(aX+dY+gZ,...).$

My attempt: I know that $SU(2)/\{\pm I\}\cong SO(3)$. Also, $-I$ acts trivially on $V_2$, so $SO(3)$ acts on $V_2$. I guess I need to use this to show $k_n[X,Y,Z]^{SO(3)}$ is isomorphic to $(S^n V_2)^{SU(2)}$. However, I am not sure how to prove this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you need to actually show the isomophism or is it enough to just show that the two vector spaces have the same dimension? The latter looks a lot easier to prove.

Comment: I just need to show that they have the same dimension

Comment: Sorry I misread your notation earlier. I have deleted the answer and will reconsider your question.

Comment: Since now that I've delete my answer and took your comments along with it, would you mind editing the question to include the clarifications on the notation for invariants and specifying the action of $SO(3)$? It would also help others who might be able to answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can replace the group $SU(2)$ with $SL_2$ for this question as $SU(2)$ is the maximal compact subgroup of $SL_2$, so the vector space of invariants does not change. Moreover, we can also replace $V_2$ with $V=\mathfrak{sl}_2$, the Lie algebra of $SL_2$, since $V_2$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ are isomorphic as $SL_2$ modules.

Note that the action of $SL_2$ on $V$ is exactly how the map $SL_2\rightarrow SO(3)$ is achieved: $SL_2$ acts on the three dimensional vector space $V$, so it gives a map $SL_2\rightarrow GL_3$. Moreover, $SL_2$ preserves the Killing form of $V=\mathfrak{sl}_2$, hence the image lies in $SO(3)$. You already mentioned that this map is surjective.

The claim immediately follows: Note that $\mathbb{C}_n[X,Y,Z]$ and $S^n(V^*)$ are isomorphic, since $V$ is three dimensional and $S^n(V^*)$ is isomorphic to the space of polynomials of degree $n$ on $V$. Moreover, $SL_2$ modules are self-dual; thus, $S^n(V^*)=S^n(V)$.

Since $SL_2$ acts on $V$ "just like" $SO(3)$, the representations $SL_2$ on $S^n(V)$ and $SO(3)$ on $\mathbb{C}_n[X,Y,Z]$ are the same.

I know the proof is a bit loose, feel free to ask anything.

Answer (score 0):

I will give a very rough sketch of how I think this can be proven.

To establish the isomorphism between invariants, we could try to establish the isomorphisms of the representations themselves.

As a first step, we need to use the correspondence between $n$-symmetric tensors and degree-$n$ homogeneous polynomials. We can define this correspondence by defining it between the separable tensors and monomials. Pick a basis for $V_2$, say $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$, then we can map a tensor of the form $\operatorname{Sym}(v_{i_1}\otimes \dots \otimes v_{i_n})$ to a monomial $X^a Y^b Z^c$, where $a, b, c$ count the number of times $v_1, v_2, v_3$ appears in the tensor, respectively. Through this correspondence, we can interpret $k_n[X, Y, Z]$ as the $n$-th symmetric power of the $3$-dimensional space of linear homogeneous polynomials in $X, Y, Z$, namely $k_1[X, Y, Z]$. It shouldn't be too hard to show that this correspondence is equivariant. It would probably follow from working through how the representation behaves on a symmetric power.

Next we may note that [symmetric powers are functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_functor), so we need only show that the representations $V_2$ (technically of $SU(2)/\{\pm I\}$) and $k_1[X,Y,Z]$ are isomrophic. Since these are just the three dimensional irreps of the two groups (or at least the right action versions), this is a standard result.

---

This proof idea sort of dodges the question of "what are the invariants". For $SO(3)$, this turns out not so hard to answer. [Invariant polynomials of $SO(3)$ are all of the form $\phi(X^2+Y^2+Z^2)$ for some polynomial $\phi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1982398/165060), which means that $k_n[X,Y,Z]^{SO(3)} = \langle (X^2+Y^2+Z^2)^{n/2} \rangle$ when $n$ is even, and trivial otherwise. For $SU(2)$, describing symmetric polynomials are a bit trickier, but you can [decompose $S^n V_2$ into irreps](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3702737/165060), and as it turns out, when $n$ is even you get exactly one invariant.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "However, I am not sure how to prove this. Can anyone help?"

**Answer:** @user14411 - If $V:=\mathbb{C}\{e_1,e_2\}$ and $V^*:=\mathbb{C}\{x_1,x_2\}$ and if $V_2 \cong Sym^2(V^*)$ you would get

$$F1.\text{  }Sym^n(V_2) \cong Sym^n(Sym^2(V^*)),$$

and since $G:=SU(2)$ is semi simple, there is a decomposition

$$P1.\text{  } Sym^n(Sym^2(V)) \cong \oplus_{\lambda} V(\lambda)$$

with $V(\lambda)$ an irreducible $G$-module. There is an equality

$$Sym^n(Sym^2(V))^{G} \cong \oplus_{\lambda} V(\lambda)^G$$

and I believe there are "lists" giving formulas for the dimension $dim(V(\lambda)^G)$
for such $\lambda$. If $F1$ holds and if you know the decomposition in $P1$ you get a formula. Much effort has been put into constructing the invariants $V(\lambda)^G$ and into calculating such dimensions.

Similarly: The vector space $k_n[x,y,z] \cong Sym^n(k\{x,y,z\})$ is the symmetric power of the dual $W^*$ of the standard representation $W$ of $SO(3)$, and I believe there are lists giving  generators and dimensions for $Sym^n(W^*)^{SO(3)}$. Look up "invariant theory".

In general if $\mathbb{S}_{\lambda}, \mathbb{S}_{\mu}$ are Schur functors and $V$ is a finite dimensional $G$-module with $G$ a semi simple algebraic group, it follows there is a direct sum decomposition into irreducible $G$-modules $W_i$:

$$ \mathbb{S}_{\lambda}(\mathbb{S}_{\mu}(V)) \cong \oplus_i W_i.$$

And if you seek $\mathbb{S}_{\lambda}(\mathbb{S}_{\mu}(V))^G$ you should first calculate $W_i^G$.